# SQL query for segregating max and min values of a column in two different columns say Val1 and Val2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have below table:

ID  DateVal  Val 
1  1/1/2010   a
1  2/2/2010   b
1  3/3/2010   c
2  4/4/2010   d
2  5/5/2010   e
2  6/6/2010   f
3  7/7/2010   g
3  8/8/2010   h
3  9/9/2010   i

I need below:

ID  Val1  Val2
1      a       c
2      d       f
3      g       i

i.e. the Val at min date in column 'Val1' and Val and max date in column 'Val2'.
What all queries are there to achieve this output and which one is easiest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DDL

```
with T as (
select 1 as id, to_date('01.01.2010','DD.MM.YYYY') dt, 'a' val
from dual union all
select 1 as id, to_date('02.02.2010','DD.MM.YYYY') dt, 'b' val
from dual union all
select 1 as id, to_date('03.03.2010','DD.MM.YYYY') dt, 'c' val
from dual union all
select 2 as id, to_date('04.04.2010','DD.MM.YYYY') dt, 'd' val
from dual union all
select 2 as id, to_date('05.05.2010','DD.MM.YYYY') dt, 'e' val
from dual union all
select 2 as id, to_date('06.06.2010','DD.MM.YYYY') dt, 'f' val
from dual union all
select 3 as id, to_date('07.07.2010','DD.MM.YYYY') dt, 'g' val
from dual union all
select 3 as id, to_date('08.08.2010','DD.MM.YYYY') dt, 'h' val
from dual union all
select 3 as id, to_date('09.09.2010','DD.MM.YYYY') dt, 'i' val
from dual)
```

Code

```
  select 
  id,
  max(val) keep (dense_rank first order by dt) as maxs,
  max(val) keep (dense_rank first order by dt desc) as mins from t 
group by id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
with t1 as 
 (select ID, min(dtval) dtval, min(val) val from date_val group by ID), 

t2 as
 (select ID, max(dtval) dtval, max(val) val from date_val group by ID)

select t1.id, t1.val val1, t2.val val2 from t1 join t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: This does not do what the question asked.

Comment: The question was asked by myself and I tried this query and it returns the same table I wanted as output in my question.. What do you think is wrong with the query? @jva

Comment: The same table was a coincidence. Try changing Val to (c,b,a) for first 3 rows instead of (a,b,c) and test again.

Comment: Yes, if that's the case, it won't work and that is why I too voted for first answer :)